# RenderControl causes NullReferenceException when called from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Some background info: I am trying to send an HTML email, containing a number of Charts, from a thread running on a ASP.NET server (started in Appication_Start).

In it's simplest form I have the following code, called from a thread running on the server:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

Chart c = new Chart();
c.RenderControl(hw); <-- NullReferenceException
```

Debug info:

```
      StackTrace:
           at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.GetHandlerUrl()
           at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.GetUrl(String query, String fileKey, String currentGuid)
           at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.GetChartImageUrl(MemoryStream stream, String imageExt)
           ...
```

When I call this piece of code from any aspx page, there is no problem. Also calling RenderControl() for a Label is no problem.

My suspicion is that there need to be some variables initialized before one may call the RenderControl() function of the Chart object, and that these variables are automatically in place when calling this function from a aspx page.

My question is then, what variables/objects does RenderControl() need to execute successfully?

Comment: Is there any documentation? If so, what does it say?

Comment: The closest I could get to an answer with a google search is this [link](http://goo.gl/xknkS). It seems to have something to do with "HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath".

Comment: I was rather talking about, are there examples for this Control? Is it a Standard control?

Comment: @bash.d If I understand you correctly, yes the RenderControl() method is documented here: [link](http://goo.gl/fnuHI), but I don't see anything (or maybe I'm just missing it?) that could help me for this particular problem.

Comment: @bash.d Sorry, my first comment was not a reply to you. Yes it is a standard control that comes with .net 4. The charting library is documented here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: ... previous comment pointed to the wrong link. [Correct one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx)